# The attempt to connect to the report server failed. ssrs reporting

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

[image]

Hi, I am having problem while connecting to ssrs report. My report is running successfully on the server and i am attaching screen shot of the report also.
Client Code:

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://nysa31:8080/Reports_MS2008");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "~/New Item";

        ReportParameter[] Params = new ReportParameter[1];

        Params[0] = new ReportParameter("EmployeeID", "990");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(Params);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I am getting this error. **The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.]**

Comment: How do you log into the report server?  If you are using windows auth, does this match your asp.net authentication, and have you enabled impersonation?

Comment: @Paddy, thanks for your reply. I am using windows authentication. Reporting server is on my development machine. I don't know what's going wrong at my end.

Answer (score 1):

The Report Server URL you have set seems to be the Report Manager URL.
Enter the Report Server URL to resolve the issue.

Comment: This was my problem, I'm such a dope!

Comment: How can you tell his Report Server URL looked like a Report Manager URL?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a bit of a read about accessing SSRS via windows auth, e.g.:

http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2010/01/report-viewer-control-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

use

http:/**/N**ysa31:8080/Reports_MS2008

instead of

http://**n**ysa31:8080/Reports_MS2008

and folder names must  starts with Uppercase letter.

because \n and \r  are new line charectors. path name mayn't work .